# Need help implementing an example in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite

Im trying to run this example in Colab https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_segmentation/raspberry_pi
but i cant make it because the example use webcam. Anyone have a different version of this example which use image, video or gif? Or can help in making one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can update the example yourself.
Remove the lines that tries to open the camera, and update this line which tries to capture image from the camera video with your image instead

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_segmentation/raspberry_pi/segment.py#L76